# Angular App doesn't work when injecting a pagination dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-controller

I'm building a simple Sigle Page Application with AngularJs, which retrieves data stored on a server-based application. When I try to inject the pagination directive, the application doesn't work, where it shows only the navigation bar. 
I've followed [this](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) tutorial.

Moreover, the console doesn't show any error. 
Below are the files where I'm trying to implement the pagination:

**main.html**:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h2 id="tables">Pagination in Angular Js</h2>
</div>
<div ng-controller="UsersList">
    <table class="table striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <!--<th>Status</th>-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr dir-paginate="user in users | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
                <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.created_at}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" max-size="10" template-url="app/main/dirPagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

**main.js**:

```
angular.module('Js-Users-App', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']).controller('UsersList', UsersList);

UsersList.$inject = ['$scope', 'userDataFactory', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'];

function UsersList($scope, userDataFactory){
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;

    // Get the list of users
    userDataFactory.userList().then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    });
}
```

**user-data-factory.js**:

```
angular.module('Js-Users-App').factory('userDataFactory', userDataFactory);

function userDataFactory($http) {
    return {
        userList: userList
    };

    function userList() {
        return $http.get("users.json").then(complete).catch(failed);
    }

    function complete(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function failed(error) {
        console.log(error.statusText);
    }
}
```

dir-paginate is declared in the file below:

```
<html ng-app="Js-Users-App">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Js Users</title>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="white" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" href="#/" class="brand-logo">Js Users</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#/add">Add</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
                <li><a href="#/add">Add</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>



    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/dirPagination.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/main/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/user-data-factory/user-data-factory.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the script is located inside the `js` folder. 
The application is running on a simple web server, started with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.
I can't find the problem. Also because I still don't know how to debug very well. Is it because the application is not loading the new directive? Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**
I've made a plunk to show you the project structure and the entire code: [http://plnkr.co/edit/LoICEnE5nkwLDvsu7URD](http://Plunker)

Comment: What's angularUtils? Where's  dir-paginate defined? The question cannot be answered because it needs http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Consider providing a plunk that replicates the problem.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: There's no dirPagination. It's unclear if the directive is even executed. Consider providing a workable plunk that replicates the problem. Because it's not a thing that can be solved by reading the code.

Comment: Here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/LoICEnE5nkwLDvsu7URD

Comment: Script paths were messy. Here's a fork, http://plnkr.co/edit/M4fzbkaufraewNHI9Lwq?p=preview . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-app` shouldn't be defined on `<html>` element, unless proven otherwise. This can result in undesirable behaviour when jQuery is loaded.

jQuery should be loaded before Angular and other dependencies that may use of it (Materialize).

`Js-Users-App` module is being redefined:

```
angular.module('Js-Users-App', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']).controller('UsersList', UsersList);
```

This eliminates router configuration, so the application does nothing. The module should be defined once, with all module dependencies:

```
angular.module("Js-Users-App", ["ngRoute", 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
```

After that `angular.module("Js-Users-App")` should be used only as a getter (no second argument).

`UsersList` controller injects `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` for no good reason, this will result in error because there's no such service - it's a directive. It should be omitted.